# Where can I find a specific photo from the Vietnam war?

Tags: military, vietnam-war, photograph

I’m looking for a specific type photo which I’ve seen before but now I can’t seem to locate it. The photo was of a group of American infantrymen marching across some mountainous jungle area in Vietnam, and in the background you could see what looked like a stone temple. One of the Americans at the front was African American I believe, and might have had an M60 on his back. Their were about 4-5 in the picture I think. Anyone know this photo?

Comment: Where have you looked?

Comment: @MCW: Google, I’ve seen the image before so I feel like it’s relatively popular, but when I’m actively searching for it it’s hard to find, go figure.

Comment: What type of sources you were likely to look at to observe this photo? Beyond just a general image search, there are image collections at [Time](https://time.com/vietnam-photos/), [Life](https://www.life.com/tag/vietnam-war/), [API](http://www.apimages.com/Collection/Landing/The-Vietnam-War-1955-1975/9809a9f33a29450aad2121c3385c68d7), [Alamy](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/vietnam-war.html?sortBy=relevant), [Getty](https://www.gettyimages.com/photos/vietnam-war), and the [National Archives](https://www.archives.gov/education/lessons/vietnam-photos), just to list a few.